# CanExecute command carries out update instead of Execute command

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

I have created methods in C# visual studio 2010 that disable or enable buttons in a record using wpf commands as below:

```
     private void CanSavePageCommandExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        **if (studentsViewSource != null && studentsViewSource.View != null && novelDataSetTableAdapter.Update(novelDataSet.students) > 0)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
            //e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.CanExecute = false;
        }
    }**
```

should be:

```
  private void CanSavePageCommandExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

       e.CanExecute = studentsViewSource != null && this.novelDataSet.HasChanges();
       e.Handled = true;

    }

     private void OnSavePageCommandExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (novelDataSetTableAdapter.Update(novelDataSet.students) > 0)

            MessageBox.Show("Entries have been updated !", "DATA STATUS");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred!", "DATA NOT SAVED");
    }
```

The 'CanSavePageCommandExecute' is supposed to just disable the SAVE button if the enclosed conditions are met. It actually does that but it goes a step further and saves the data to the database.
The 'OnSavePageCommandExecute' command is not carried out even if I just test using MessageBox.show.
How do I prevent the CanExecute command from saving data to just enabling and disabling button based on changes made to the datasets?

I am not using MVVM but this is part of the Xaml code from a user control:

```
  <UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="New" 
            CanExecute="CanNewPageCommandExecute" Executed="OnNewPageCommandExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.PreviousPage" 
            CanExecute="CanPreviousPageCommandExecute" Executed="OnPreviousPageCommandExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.NextPage"
            CanExecute="CanNextPageCommandExecute" Executed="OnNextPageCommandExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="FirstPage"
            CanExecute="CanPreviousPageCommandExecute" Executed="OnFirstPageCommandExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="LastPage"
            CanExecute="CanNextPageCommandExecute" Executed="OnLastPageCommandExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:student.saves}"
            CanExecute="CanSavePageCommandExecute" Executed="OnSavePageCommandExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="Delete"
            CanExecute="CanDeletePageCommandExecute" Executed="OnDeletePageCommandExecute" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>

<Border Width="Auto" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
    <dxlc:LayoutControl Name="layoutControl1" Cursor="Arrow">
        <dxlc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical" Height="303">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Height="160" Width="160" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,0,0,20">
                <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/college12;component/images/prime.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" TileMode="None" />
                </Border.Background>
                <Image Height="150" Name="studypixx" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="150" UseLayoutRounding="False" DataContext="{StaticResource studentsViewSource}" Source="{Binding Path=studyphoto, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Border>
            <Button Content="Upload Photo" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="studentphotoupload" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" ToolTip="Inserts photo" Background="#FFEC3B3B" BorderBrush="Black" Cursor="Hand" Click="studentphotoupload_Click" />
            <TextBox Name="photo_text" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Visible" Text="{Binding Path=studyphoto, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" DataContext="{StaticResource studentsViewSource}" />
            <dxlc:LayoutGroup Name="layoutGroup3" View="GroupBox" Width="160" Height="62">
                <Button Content="NEW STUDENT" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="addstudent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="93" Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Cursor="Hand" />
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
        </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
        <dxlc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">
            <dxlc:LayoutGroup Name="layoutGroup1" View="GroupBox" Height="238" UseLayoutRounding="True" Orientation="Vertical" Width="450" DragScrolling="False" Header="{Binding Path=surname}" DataContext="{StaticResource studentsViewSource}">
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="First Name" Name="layoutItem1">
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="first_name" FontFamily="Consolas" UseLayoutRounding="False" CharacterCasing="Upper" MaskSaveLiteral="True" Mask="[a-zA-Z]+" MaskType="RegEx" EditValue="{Binding Path=firstname, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Middle Name" Name="layoutItem2">
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="other_name" FontFamily="Consolas" UseLayoutRounding="False" CharacterCasing="Upper" MaskSaveLiteral="True" Mask="[a-zA-Z]+" MaskType="RegEx" EditValue="{Binding Path=othername, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Surname" Name="layoutItem3">
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="other_surname" FontFamily="Consolas" UseLayoutRounding="False" CharacterCasing="Upper" MaskSaveLiteral="True" Mask="[a-zA-Z]+" MaskType="RegEx" EditValue="{Binding Path=surname, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Email" Name="layoutItem10">
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="email_address" EditValue="{Binding Path=email, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Birth Date" Name="layoutItem4">
                        <dxe:DateEdit Name="birth_date" Mask="d/MM/yyyy" MaskSaveLiteral="False" MaskType="DateTime" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="12" EditValue="{Binding Path=birthdate, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Enrol Date" Name="layoutItem5">
                        <dxe:DateEdit Name="enrol_date" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" MaskType="DateTime" MaskSaveLiteral="False" Mask="d/MM/yyyy" UseLayoutRounding="False" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="12" EditValue="{Binding Path=enroldate, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Enrol NO." Name="layoutItem6">
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="enrol_no" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="10" EditValue="{Binding Path=enrolnum, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Phone NO." Name="layoutItem9">
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="phone_no" Mask="(\d?\d?\d?\d)\d\d-\d\d-\d\d" MaskType="Regular" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="10" MaskBeepOnError="False" MaskSaveLiteral="False" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" EditValue="{Binding Path=phone, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Address" Name="layoutItem7">
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="address" FontFamily="Consolas" UseLayoutRounding="False" CharacterCasing="Upper" EditValue="{Binding Path=address, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Town/City" Name="layoutItem8">
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="town_city" FontFamily="Consolas" UseLayoutRounding="False" CharacterCasing="Upper" Mask="[a-zA-Z]+" MaskType="RegEx" EditValue="{Binding Path=town, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
            <dxlc:LayoutGroup Name="layoutGroup2" View="GroupBox" Width="450">
                <Button Content="FIRST" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="firststudent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Cursor="Hand" Command="NavigationCommands.FirstPage" />
                <Button Content="PREVIOUS" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="previoustudent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="NavigationCommands.PreviousPage" ToolTip="Preceding student record" Cursor="Hand" />
                <Button Content="NEXT" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="nextstudent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="NavigationCommands.NextPage" ToolTip="Next student record" Cursor="Hand" />
                <Button Content="LAST" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="laststudent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Cursor="Hand" Command="NavigationCommands.LastPage" />
                <Button Content="SAVE" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="savestudent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Cursor="Hand" Command="{x:Static local:student.saves}"/>
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
        </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
    </dxlc:LayoutControl>
</Border>
```

Comment: Can you show the xaml where u binding the command . I dnt think this is the correct way to bind commands if u using mvvm. You need to fire the event CanExecuteChanged after setting CanExecute

Comment: well I'm guessing the saving is because of `novelDataSetTableAdapter.Update(novelDataSet.students)` in your `CanExecute(...)` function. CanExecute runs periodically to check if the associated control for the command should be enabled or not, Now if your Update function actually "updates" in the background, not rly something wrong with the canexecute. What you need is to have a function like "CanUpdate(...)" which should prolly return a bool saying if it can or cannot update **without actually updating** and use that function in your `CanSavePageCommandExecute(...)`.

Comment: @Viv Actually I found it what is triggering the update is function is the updatesourcetrigger which I had set to propertychanged. I still dont understand why the CanExecute command should activate this. Also I have made new changes  to the code which I guess solves my problem...Thanks Viv and  ethicallogics for ur suggestions!